# Android-studio ERROR: Cannot add task 'copyDebugIconFonts' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, fonts, icons

I have **React Native** project. When i build **Android** version i get an **ERROR**: Cannot add task 'copyDebugIconFonts' as a task with that name already exists. And in my terminal i have this error: 
**FAILURE**: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/evgeniykireev/openCalls/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  Cannot add task 'copyDebugIconFonts' as a task with that name already exists.

**My build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**My fonts.gradle:**

```
def config = project.hasProperty("vectoricons") ? project.vectoricons : [];

def iconFontsDir = config.iconFontsDir ?: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts";
def iconFontNames = config.iconFontNames ?: [ "*.ttf" ];

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    android.applicationVariants.all { def variant ->
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def targetPath = variant.dirName

        // Create task for copying fonts
        def currentFontTask = tasks.create(
                name: "copy${targetName}IconFonts",
                type: Copy) {
            into("${buildDir}/intermediates")

            iconFontNames.each { fontName ->

              from(iconFontsDir) {
                include(fontName)
                into("assets/${targetPath}/fonts/")
              }

              // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2+ new asset directory
              from(iconFontsDir) {
                include(fontName)
                into("merged_assets/${variant.name}/merge${targetName}Assets/out/fonts/")
              }

              // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4+ new asset directory
              from(iconFontsDir) {
                include(fontName)
                into("merged_assets/${variant.name}/out/fonts/")
              }
            }
        }

        currentFontTask.dependsOn("merge${targetName}Resources")
        currentFontTask.dependsOn("merge${targetName}Assets")

        [
            "processArmeabi-v7a${targetName}Resources",
            "processX86${targetName}Resources",
            "processUniversal${targetName}Resources",
            "process${targetName}Resources"
        ].each { name ->
            Task dependentTask = tasks.findByPath(name);

            if (dependentTask != null) {
                dependentTask.dependsOn(currentFontTask)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me please)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this package "react-native-vector-icons" has been added multiple times in your build.gradle file.

To solve this simply go to **android>build.gradle** and search "react-native-vector-icons". If you found this twice then remove that line. for example i just commented out this =>

// apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Comment: It happened to me when. I once installed using npm and had to add this line manually, since then I was always doing it. Today I installed it with yarn and it looks like it added the second line automatically. And he started to make this mistake. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I had this line when I originally added react-native-vector-icons, but then much later I added the Notifee package which apparently uses the vector icons also. I had to comment out the *only* appearance of this line in my build.gradle to solve my build error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I remove this code in Android/setting.gradle

```
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to: go to android->app->build.graddle not android->graddle
find following mentioned twice. comment one of those. In my case it worked.
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).